# How to clone a d3.geo.projection?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to create a projection like:

```
var p1 = d3.geo.cylindricalEqualArea()
  .scale(200)
  .translate([0, 30]);
```

then clone that:

```
var p2 = someCloneFunction(p1)
  .scale(600)
  .translate([-10, 0]);
```

and leave p1 unaffected.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) should help.

Comment: the projection object is a function and some properties and thus i think special code needs to be written.  this:

    var clone = $.extend(true, {}, projection);

does not work.

Comment: Have you tried the approach that converts it to JSON and back?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff ya, i ran though all the different ideas in that question.  some pretty creative stuff, but no luck.